# Splitting two comma delimited strings into itemized array

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to create a register of candidates who have attended training on various topics. The trainer completes a Google Form and selects the candidates from a checkbox list, and also the training topics from a checkbox list. The result is two comma delimited strings, which I want to split into a itemized array as follows:

Original form response

```
| Candidate            | Training                    |  
+----------------------+-----------------------------+  
| Peter, Susan, John   | Algebra, Geometry, Calculus |
```

Desired output:

```
| Candidate    |  Training  |
+--------------+------------+  
| Peter        | Algebra    |
| Peter        | Geometry   |
| Peter        | Calculus   |
| Susan        | Algebra    |
| Susan        | Geometry   |
| Susan        | Calculus   |
| John         | Algebra    |
| John         | Geometry   |
| John         | Calculus   |
```

There will be multiple form submissions, and trainers can submit more than one response.

I have given it a go myself, this is what I've come up with: `=ARRAYFORMULA({transpose(trim(split(join(",", rept(C2:C&",", if(len(E2:E)>0, (len(E2:E)-len(substitute(E2:E, ",",""))+1),)) ),","))),transpose(trim(split(join(",", rept(E2:E&",", if(len(C2:C)>0, (len(C2:C)-len(substitute(C2:C, ",",""))+1),)) ),",")))})` 
This successfully splits and repeats both strings the correct number of times, however it repeats it in the same order. The implication of this (with reference to the example in my original question) is that you get the following undesirable output:

```
| Candidate    |  Training  |
+--------------+------------+  
| Peter        | Algebra    |
| Susan        | Geometry   |
| John         | Calculus   |
| Peter        | Algebra    |
| Susan        | Geometry   |
| John         | Calculus   |
```

Any advice? I'd sincerely appreciate anyone's help with this! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place for questions/answers - not a free code-writing service.

Comment: I have given it a go myself, this is what I've come up with:  `=ARRAYFORMULA({transpose(trim(split(join(",", rept(C2:C&",", if(len(E2:E)>0, (len(E2:E)-len(substitute(E2:E, ",",""))+1),)) ),","))),transpose(trim(split(join(",", rept(E2:E&",", if(len(C2:C)>0, (len(C2:C)-len(substitute(C2:C, ",",""))+1),)) ),",")))})` This successfully splits and repeats both strings the correct number of times, however it repeats it in the same order. The implication of this (with reference to the example in my original question) is that you get a person doing the same subject. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AmHYWnFLY1F-dG1oTHQ5SS1uUzhvTnZTSHNzMjdDaVE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=<YOUR_CALLBACK>";
$.getJSON(url,{}, function (d) { console.log(d); });
```

Now "d" is your object...